# goldengate : Metadata format of the definitions file for table does not match trail format

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

getting the below error when starting replicat...

```
2019-02-01 12:46:28  INFO    OGG-03059  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  Operating system character set identified as UTF-8.
2019-02-01 12:46:28  INFO    OGG-02695  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  ANSI SQL parameter syntax is used for parameter parsing.
2019-02-01 12:46:28  INFO    OGG-03515  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  Source character set us7ascii is specified with the SOURCECHARSET parameter.
2019-02-01 12:46:28  INFO    OGG-03528  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  The source database character set, as determined from the table definition file, is us7ascii.
2019-02-01 12:46:28  INFO    OGG-15052  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  Using Java class path: ggjava/ggjava.jar:ggjava/resources/lib/optional/log4j-1.2.17.jar:ggjava/resources/lib/optional/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar.
2019-02-01 12:46:29  INFO    OGG-01815  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  Virtual Memory Facilities for: COM
    anon alloc: mmap(MAP_ANON)  anon free: munmap
    file alloc: mmap(MAP_SHARED)  file free: munmap
    target directories:
    /opt/c7/oracle/product/kogg/12.2.0.1/dirtmp.
2019-02-01 12:46:29  INFO    OGG-00996  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  REPLICAT RMS01 started.
2019-02-01 12:46:29  INFO    OGG-02243  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  Opened trail file /db/c7/ogg/trail/rp000000000 at 2019-02-01 12:46:29.939039.
2019-02-01 12:46:29  ERROR   OGG-02913  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  Metadata format of the definitions file for table SCH_MCI.NDIRECT_COLOR does not match trail format.
2019-02-01 12:46:29  ERROR   OGG-01668  Oracle GoldenGate Delivery, rms01.prm:  PROCESS ABENDING.
2019-02-01 12:46:40  INFO    OGG-00987  Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter:  GGSCI command (oraclegg): info all.
2019-02-01 12:53:32  INFO    OGG-00987  Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter:  GGSCI command (oraclegg): info all.
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/c1221/gg-winux/GMESG/oggus.htm):

> **Cause**: The definitions file uses a metadata format that is incompatible with the trail format.
>
> **Action**: Regenerate the definitions file using the correct metadata format then restart the application.